# Replace subqueries to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to improve the performance of the following Query in SQL Server:

```
WITH s
AS (
    SELECT src.[ITEMID] AS [Item Code]
        ,po.[ORDERACCOUNT] AS [Order Account]
        ,vpsj.[INVOICEACCOUNT] AS [Invoice Account]
        ,vpsj.[PURCHID] AS [PO Number]
        ,src.[INVENTDIMID] AS [Inventory Dimension Id]
        ,po.[PURCHREQLINEREFID] AS [Reference Id]
        ,po.[PURCHPOOLID] AS [Purchase Pool Code]
        ,po.[ITEMBUYERGROUPID] AS [Inventory Buyer Group Code]
        ,cast(0 AS [bigint]) AS [Category Id]
        ,(
            SELECT TOP (1) lt.LEDGERDIMENSION
            FROM [dbo].[EALedgerTransactions] lt
            WHERE lt.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
                AND lt.[VOUCHERDATAAREAID] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
                AND lt.[VOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
                AND lt.[POSTINGTYPE] IN (82,83)
            ) AS [Ledger Dimension Id]
        ,(
            SELECT TOP (1) lt.MAINACCOUNTID
            FROM [dbo].[EALedgerTransactions] lt
            WHERE lt.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
                AND lt.[VOUCHERDATAAREAID] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
                AND lt.[VOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
                AND lt.[POSTINGTYPE] IN (82,83)
            ) AS [Main Account Id]
        ,src.[RECORDID] AS [Record Id]
        ,src.[COMPANYCODE] AS [Company Code]
        ,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, po.[CREATEDDATEANDTIME] - getutcdate() + getutcdate()), 0) AS [PO Date],
        po.[CURRENCYCODE] AS [Currency Code]
        ,src.[SOURCEDOCUMENTLINE] AS [Source Document Line Id]
        ,src.[ACCOUNTINGDATE] AS [Transaction Date]
        ,vpsj.[PACKINGSLIPID] AS [Product Receipt]
        ,cast(NULL AS [nvarchar](20)) AS [Invoice Number]
        ,src.[PURCHUNIT] AS [Purchase Unit]
        ,cast(NULL AS [nvarchar](20)) AS [Inventory Unit]
        ,po.[POAMOUNT] / nullif(po.[POQUANTITY], 0.0) AS [Purchase Price]
        ,src.[QTY] AS [Receipt Quantity]
        ,src.[INVENTQTY] AS [Receipt Inventory Quantity]
        ,src.[VALUEMST] AS [Receipt Amount Master]
        ,(
            SELECT sum(QTY) AS QTY
            FROM [dbo].[EAVendorPackingslipTransactions] pst
            WHERE pst.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
                AND pst.[COMPANYCODE] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
                AND pst.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
            ) AS [Voucher Quantity]
        ,(
            SELECT sum(ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT) AS ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT
            FROM [dbo].[EALedgerTransactions] lt
            WHERE lt.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
                AND lt.[VOUCHERDATAAREAID] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
                AND lt.[VOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
                AND lt.[POSTINGTYPE] IN (82,83)
            ) AS [GRNI Amount Master]
        ,(
            SELECT sum(TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT) AS TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT
            FROM [dbo].[EALedgerTransactions] lt
            WHERE lt.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
                AND lt.[VOUCHERDATAAREAID] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
                AND lt.[VOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
                AND lt.[POSTINGTYPE] IN (82,83)
            ) AS [GRNI Amount]
    FROM [dbo].[EAVendorPackingslipTransactions] src
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [RECORDID]
            ,[INVOICEACCOUNT]
            ,[COMPANYCODE]
            ,[PURCHID]
            ,[PACKINGSLIPID]
            ,[ACCOUNTINGDATE]
            ,[LEDGERVOUCHER]
            ,[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
            ,rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY [RECORDID] ORDER BY [VENDPACKINGSLIPVERSION_RECORDID] DESC
                ) AS [RANK]
        FROM [dbo].[EAVendorPackingslipJournals] vpsj
        ) vpsj ON vpsj.[RECORDID] = src.[VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR]
        AND vpsj.[RANK] = 1
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EAPurchaseOrders] po ON po.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
        AND po.[COMPANYCODE] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
        AND po.[INVENTORYTRANSACTIONID] = src.[INVENTTRANSID]
    )
```

The problem seems to be in the subquieres, I have been trying to make different joins to replace the subquieres, but no lucky so far (don't have the expected values).

Any ideas on how to replace the subqueries or anything else?

Execution plan:
[image]

Comment: 4 of those subqueries are *the same* subquery with a different expressions in the `SELECT`; I would start by moving those 4 into 1 query in the `FROM` (using an `APPLY`).

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: The *DRY* principle applies to SQL as it does any other language, where it usually has far more reaching performance, concurrency and scalability impact.

Comment: @Stu: if only that were true. For T-SQL in particular, repeating things is often either unavoidable, or if not applied results in severe performance trouble (like helpfully extracting a common expression into a scalar-valued function, or even prematurely materializing it in a subquery so you don't have to repeat it). While ensuring that subqueries don't get *unnecessarily* evaluated in a repeated fashion is certainly a good idea, this has little to do wtih DRY, and proceeding as if SQL was a programming language just sets you up for disappointment.

Comment: Nested `VIEW`s are a *great* example of when DRY does *not* work well in SQL Server; these can actually perform very poorly. As @JeroenMostert mentioned, as well, scalar functions have a reputation of performing poorly; they are now inlinable but the caveats that does with that and that if you are working with 2017 or prior means that avoidance is still often recommended. Often this does mean that repetition in objects can and does happen because to be performant repetition is actually best.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes specifically was referring to querying the same table multiple times in a query with same or similar criteria which can usually be avoided; that's the R I was referring to. as always it depends of course.

Comment: You could try CROSS APPLY on the TOP sub queries. We would need to see the execution plan, also calls SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON; to see what the query is really doing such as logical reads and cpu time.

Comment: I tried this:

CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT MIN(lt.LEDGERDIMENSION) AS [Ledger Dimension Id], MIN(lt.MAINACCOUNTID)AS [Main Account Id], SUM(ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT) AS [GRNI Amount Master], SUM(TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT) AS [GRNI Amount]
    FROM [dbo].[EALedgerTransactions] lt
    WHERE lt.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION] AND lt.[COMPANYCODE] = src.[COMPANYCODE] AND lt.[VOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER] AND lt.[POSTINGTYPE] IN (82,83)
  ) AS lt

 and there is a small improvement. The execution plan show that the issue seems to be on the Index Spool (Eager Spool).

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to test without having data, but can you try this query as a starting point for you:

```
select src.[ITEMID],src.[PARTITION],src.[COMPANYCODE],src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
        ,max(lt.LEDGERDIMENSION) as [Ledger Dimension Id]
        ,max(lt.MAINACCOUNTID) as [Main Account Id]
        ,sum(lt.QTY) AS [Voucher Quantity] 
        ,sum(lt.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT) as [GRNI Amount Master]
        ,sum(lt.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT) as [GRNI Amount]
FROM [dbo].[EAVendorPackingslipTransactions] src
LEFT JOIn [EALedgerTransactions] lt
on lt.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
            AND lt.[VOUCHERDATAAREAID] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
            AND lt.[VOUCHER] = src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
            AND lt.[POSTINGTYPE] IN (82,83)

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [RECORDID]
        ,[INVOICEACCOUNT]
        ,[COMPANYCODE]
        ,[PURCHID]
        ,[PACKINGSLIPID]
        ,[ACCOUNTINGDATE]
        ,[LEDGERVOUCHER]
        ,[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
        ,rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [RECORDID] ORDER BY [VENDPACKINGSLIPVERSION_RECORDID] DESC
            ) AS [RANK]
    FROM [dbo].[EAVendorPackingslipJournals] vpsj
    ) vpsj ON vpsj.[RECORDID] = src.[VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR]
    AND vpsj.[RANK] = 1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EAPurchaseOrders] po ON po.[PARTITION] = src.[PARTITION]
    AND po.[COMPANYCODE] = src.[COMPANYCODE]
    AND po.[INVENTORYTRANSACTIONID] = src.[INVENTTRANSID]
group by src.[ITEMID],src.[PARTITION],src.[COMPANYCODE],src.[COSTLEDGERVOUCHER]
```

instead of using subqueries it joins onetime to the EALedgerTransactions table, and uses then a **Group By** to make groups of data, with **MAX** to get a top 1 result and **SUM** to get the totals within the group.